# completion handler being called too early

Tags: swift, handler, completion

I am trying to run this completion handler after the label zooms out but it's being called at the very start of the function. I've watched some tutorials and read some documentation but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code.

```swift
func fadeViewInThenOut(view : UILabel, delay: TimeInterval, completion: () -> () ) {
    let animationDuration = 1.00

    // Fade in the view
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 1, animations: { () -> Void in
        view.alpha = 1
    }) { (Bool) -> Void in

        // After the animation completes, fade out the view after a delay
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: delay, animations: { () -> Void in
            view.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    completion()
}

fadeViewInThenOut(view: newwelcomeLabel, delay: 5) {
    print("hello")
}
```

Comment: **You** call it too early. Please look at the behavior of the `UIView.animate` completion handlers.

Comment: You will need to add a completion block in your second `UIView.animate` call. That is where you will want to call your `completion()` handler.

Also, you should consider taking a look at `UIViewPropertyAnimator` in place of using `UIView.animate()` functions.